# Prove cross product of unit vector with right-hand screw rule

Tags: vectors

Online, I have not found materials about it, and, still I am not convinced myself about the properties of the cross product of unit vectors. It is pretty clear that :
$$\hat i \times \hat i = i \cdot i \cdot \sin \phi = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \sin (0°) = 0 = \hat j \times \hat j = \hat k \times \hat k$$

where $\phi$ is the angle between the unit vectors.
but I don't fully understand why for example we have:
$$ \begin{array}{lcl}
1) \quad \hat i \times \hat j & = & \hat k \\
2) \quad \hat i \times \hat k & = & - \hat j \end{array}$$

I have tried to prove it using the *right-hand screw rule* :

This is my figure:
[image]

Using that rule:

for 1):

as in fig.2: looking from the top, we can see the xy plane and the z-axis has *direction* perpendicular to the plane, and its *way* towards the top, i.e. towards our eyes. Of the z-axis, or of $\hat k$, I can see the tip.

I consider a screw on the intersection of the unit vectors $\hat i, \hat j$, and with a counterclockwise rotation, I go to unscrew it, or better, the screw moves towards our eyes, **the same direction and way** of the z-axis: so the sign is positive.

for 2):

starting from fig.2, I rotate of 90° keeping firm the x-axis, therefore I obtain the fig.3, where the y-axis has gone behind, if we look from the top we can see the zx-plane  and the y-axis has the *direction* perpendicular to the plane, but, its *way* it is towards the bottom, i.e. inside the plane (or inside our paper, or inside our monitor). Of y-axis, or $\hat j$, I can see the tail.

So, I consider a screw on the intersection of the unit vectors $\hat i, \hat k$, and with a counterclockwise rotation, I go to unscrew it, or better, the screw moves towards our eyes, the **same direction** of y-axis, but, the **opposite  way** of the y-axis: so the sign is negative.

$\blacksquare$

What do you think, is it a good way to proceed, to prove that using the right-hand screw rule? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, what is your question, precisely?

Comment: @AlexProvost a way to prove that two properties using the right-hand screw rule and without the determinant.

Comment: What definition of the cross product are you using?

Comment: @AlexProvost like here : http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch12/vch12_4.html

Comment: More formally, you are defining the cross product of $u,v$ as the vector a) that is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$; b) that has length $|u| |v| \sin(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$; c) whose orientation is given by the right-hand rule. From this, isn't it clear that $i \times j = k$ and $i \times k = -j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross product between two vectors

$$\vec A=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\;,\;\;\;\vec B=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$$

is defined as

$$\vec C=\vec A\times \vec B:=\begin{vmatrix}e_1&e_2&e_3\\x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\end{vmatrix}=(x_2y_3-x_3y_2\,,\,x_3y_1-x_1y_3\,,\,x_1y_2-x_2y_1)$$

and it turns out to be a vector $\vec C$ orthogonal to the plane spanned by $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

The direction of $\vec C$ is given by the **right hand rule**.
[image]

From the defintiion we have that

- $\hat i \times \hat j=\hat k, \quad \hat j \times \hat i=-\hat k$
- $\hat j \times \hat k=\hat i, \quad \hat k \times \hat j=-\hat i$
- $\hat k \times \hat i=\hat j, \quad \hat i \times \hat k=-\hat j$